# My soup tastes tart... Is it safe to eat?

Tags: food-safety, soup

My soup tastes almost like someone poured some lemon juice into it. It smells fine, and other than being a little lemony, tastes OK. When I put it in the fridge a week ago, it didn't have that tart flavor.

What would cause this to happen? Is it safe to eat?

The soup was made from:

- Chicken broth
- Ground turkey
- Ham
- Broccoli
- Green beans
- Onion

Comment: I think keeping soup for longer then a couple of days in the fridge is not a good idea, why not freeze it when you are not going to eat  it soon? I don't know what causes the change in flavor, but I wouldn't eat 'old' food which flavor changed, just to be safe.

Comment: If you check http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer you'll see its 3 days for a soup...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would not eat any soup containing meat more than a day or two after it was cooked, and certainly not if it smelled suspicious. The logic with this kind of thing is simple. If you have any doubts, chuck it out. Not getting food poisoning is worth losing a little soup over.

Comment: "When in doubt, throw it out."

Answer (score -2):

I frequently eat things that are beginning to go a little tart, I like the flavor. The food is beginning to turn, but is probably not going to hurt you (the germs that cause illness don't add flavor to food). If the flavor is a little off, but the food is still palatable, I would have no problem eating it.

Comment: Do you have a source for your assertion that 'the germs that cause illness don't add flavour to food'?